# What alternatives do I have when encountering IMPORTDATA maximum size error in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm using the `IMPORTDATA` formula to populate a CSV file. I'm encountering an Error.

The file size is 8MB so I think that may be the issue since I've previously used this formula with no problems, do I have any alternative routes to populate this data into the sheet?

This is the formula I am using:

```
=IMPORTDATA("URL.csv")
```

I expect the entire file to upload but am encountering the error message:

> Error The resource at URL contents exceeded the maximum size.

Comment: You'd need to write a script to fetch the file, parse the csv and set it to Google sheets.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code:

```
function getBigCsv() {
  var url = 'https:URL.csv';
  var csv = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var data = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(2, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
={ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA("URL.csv"), 1000, 1); 
 QUERY(IMPORTDATA("URL.csv"), "offset 1000", 0)}
```

which translates as: if 2000 rows throw you an error then import 1000 rows and then import another 1000 under it

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried that and actually received the same error.

Comment: Here is the sheet! the file is within cell A1. thanks for the help!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kHxy01qXgm0MBv3Jz3BB1jTqGjx5yRXPwVx4E6b-5CI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: the issue is that the link is direct download. do you have a regular link which can be visited in the browser?

Comment: i've tried the same type of link with a previous file and that worked fine so i dont think the regular link where it can be visited in the browser would be the issue. do you think that would be it?